# как изогнуть изображение на bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, transform, матрицы

Можно ли деформировать изображение на bitmap , чтобы результат выглядел примерно так:

[image: изгиб изображения]

Методы матрицы (например `setPolyToPoly()` ) позволяют только растягивать и скашивать изображение , но не изгибать

Comment: Да, теоретически стандартным Matrix такое можно сделать в несколько этапов смотрите в сторону setScew или даже setSinCos, они могут задать точки в матрице так как на картинке, не забывайте расчитывать разницу Rect так как деформированная картинка будет иметь rect больше оригинала. Хороший вопрос но дать точный ответ, требует времени. Также можно попробовать найти либы для работы с этим, их довольно много. Также вы можете легко получить такой эффект с помощь стандартной анимации кстати, это наверное будет правильный ответ, сразу не подумал об этом. ViewPropertyAnim

Comment: Skew не может сдвинуть разные части bitmap на разное расстояние , создав эффект изгиба - он только сдвигает одну половину фигуры относительно указанной точки , а повторные вызовы skew лишь добавляют или уменьшают (или изменяют направление) ранее сделанный сдвиг , а setSinCos вообще просто поворачивает , что касается анимации , то изменять можно только значения существующих свойств , а такого свойства , как "кривизна сторон" у bitmap нет ,  если же речь о AnimatedVectorDrawable , то не понятно , как превратить растровый bitmap в xml файл с pathData , значения которого можно менять

Comment: кони - котлеты - мухи - люди. Кстати растр в теории можно превратить в вектор, что я могу добавить прочитав всё выше. УДачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказывается у Canvas есть методы `drawBitmapMesh()` и `drawVertices()` , которые делают именно то что нужно:

[image: изогнутое изображение]